# dynamically read/add value to the parameter of conf file with Properties

Tags: java, properties

I have a message like below in my conf file.

`text.message = Richard` has to go to `School` in `01/06/2012` / `1days`.

All highlighted field will be variable.

I want to read this `text.me` string and insert the value from my java using Properties.

I know how to read the whole string using Prop, but don't know how to read like above String which will be like.

`text.message = #name#` has to go to #place# in #date# / #days#.

1. how can I read the above string from the conf using Properties and insert data dynamically?
2. It can be either date or days in the string. How I can turn on and off between those parameters?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) API for this.

Kickoff example:

```
text.message = {0} has to go to {1} in {2,date,dd/MM/yyyy} / {3}
```

with

```
String message = properties.getProperty("text.message");
String formattedMessage = MessageFormat.format(message, "Richard", "School", new Date(), "1days");
System.out.println(formattedMessage); // Richard has to go to School in 31/05/2012 / 1days
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class, which replaces dynamic placeholders in a string with the desired values.

For example, the following code...

```
String pattern = "{0} has to go to {1} in {2,date} / {3,number,integer} days.";
String result = MessageFormat.format(pattern, "Richard", "school", new Date(), 5);
System.out.println(result);
```

...will produce the following output:

```
Richard has to go to school in 31-May-2012 / 5 days.
```

You can simply get the pattern from your `Properties` object, then apply the MessageFormat translation.