# Accessing File contents based on Key using AJAX or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My web application uses file which has been updated by other process. My application reads the content of the file using ajax

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","/config/myfile",false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Once response is received then app parses this response and shows that values on Web UI. The file contains 50 fields and whenever I want to read any single field I need to open whole file. 
Is there any way to get the values of single field based on key instead of reading whole file.

As per my understanding we need to read and open file and then parse the response text. But would like to know is there any way to reduce the file calls with any other method. 
I want to achieve this to reduce the file I/O operations. Since other processes are writing in to it and at same time my web app accessing to read the latest value.
Any other option would be appreciated.

Note :- I do not have to use any server side scripting lang option.

Regds

Comment: Try Java Properties File API. It will search on Key value basis.

Comment: Do I need to use Java for this? If yes, then i do not have this option with me.

Comment: Its simple Java.util package clases, that are used to create file an use their contents as key and value.

Comment: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843855/dynamically-read-add-value-to-the-parameter-of-conf-file-with-properties">Property File </a> example.