# Set profile based on the REST API request spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I am using configuration file segment profile-specific like :

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: tenant1
some-property: value1
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: tenant2
some-property: value2
```

and then there is POST request in which 'some-property' field will come, based on which I want to activate the profile. Request format is:

> {
> some-property: value2
> }

In the above request the value of 'some-property' is value2, so second profile should be selected because the value of 'some-property' is the request is value2 which matches with one of the property of profile tenant2. So profile tenant2 will be selected.

Comment: If you are reading it from the properties file, then you need to read all the values for the all the profiles, because you can't dynamically read the properties file. Its being loaded when the application boots up. I think for your use case, maybe you can keep this values in DB or in a file, from where you can dynamically read it based on the value coming in the Endpoint.

Comment: Or Maybe, you can do something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843855/dynamically-read-add-value-to-the-parameter-of-conf-file-with-properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamically read/add value to the parameter of conf file with Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843855/dynamically-read-add-value-to-the-parameter-of-conf-file-with-properties)

Comment: Actually, the field through which I want to set the profile is coming in the request of REST API.  So I don't know how to set it dynamically.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? What exactly you want to set and what is the field that is coming?

Comment: @Pronoy999 : I have updated the question. Please let me know if that is okay to understand.

Comment: I think you might need to read the entire config on boot up and keep it, from the request just choose the appropriate value.